# How to compute Transition Function for $T\mathbb{S}^2$ associated with stereographic projections

Tags: differential-geometry

> Compute the transition function for $T \mathbb{S}^2$ associated with the two local trivializations determined by stereographic coordinates.

The stereographic projection $\sigma : \mathbb{S}^2 \setminus \left\{ N \right\} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is given by
$$\sigma(x_1 , x_2 ) = \dfrac{ (x_1 , x_2 ) }{1 - x_2 } $$
where $N$ is the north pole.

Additionally, $\tilde{\sigma}(x) = -\sigma(-x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{S}^2 \setminus \left\{ S \right\}$ where $S$ is the south pole.

I'm not sure how to compute the transition function for $T\mathbb{S}^2$ using $\sigma$ and $\tilde{\sigma}$.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the inverse projection map $\tilde{\sigma}^{-1}:\mathbf{R}^{2} \to S^{2} \setminus\{S\}$?

Comment: Check your formula : it is not rotationaly invariant.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, no I am not familiar with calculating the inverse projection map. How would I go about doing that?